# swift - why not working my semaphore?

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy, semaphore

```
class BLEManager {
    private let bleManagerCB = BLEManagerCB()

    func checkPowered() -> Bool {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        var state : Bool?

        bleManagerCB.checkPowered()
        bleManagerCB.onCompletionPowered = { result in
            state = result
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }
        semaphore.wait()
        return state
    }
}
```

---

```
class BLEManagerCB:NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var centralManager:CBCentralManager!
    var onCompletionPowered:((_ result:Bool) -> Void)?

    func checkPowered() {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        //centralManagerDidUpdateState(delegate method) call.
    }

    //check power
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            onCompletionPowered!(true)

        } else if central.state == .poweredOff {
            onCompletionPowered!(false)
        }
    }
}
```

hi, i have a question for semaphore. look at my code please.
why my semaphore is not working?
it's matter of closure code?
i want to 'checkPowered function' is synchronous active.

Comment: 1. Because you are using the main queue for your `CBCentralManager` and then blocking the main queue with a `semaphore.wait`. 2.  Don't do this.  Deal with the fact that the world is asynchronous

Comment: @paulw11 : Sorry my mistake :) You were right :) When semaphore count becomes negative all threads expecting semaphore will be made to wait :) When count is 0 and first thread approaches for semaphore it gets one and semaphore count becomes -1 hence second thread when asks for semaphore thread will be blocked until the first thread releases the one it holds :) Hence synchronization is achieved :) I was wrong when I said if its 0 thread will be blocked :) cheers :)

Comment: thx for your comment :) I realized that I needed to change the queue for " centralManager " to active the synchronous. but it may will not be good for process.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari - I appreciate your attempt to clarify, but that description is still not correct. But it's moot: This simply is not a good use-case for semaphores. David really should excise his code of semaphores and just use async patterns.

Comment: @rob : I agree that using semaphores are not the best way to solve asynchronous pattern issues :) I explained it in comment because Paulw had pointed out a mistake in my answer (which I deleted later) and wanted to thank  him for letting me know the issue and wanted to clarify why I got confused :) The comment above is not to convince anybody to use semaphore :)

Comment: One of you should post an answer, so this question can be marked resolved.

Comment: @Paulw11, you should feel free to post as answer, if you want.

Comment: your advice was a big help. now i use async patterns :)
i wanna resolved to this question. post an answer please.